# Group by week using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and I want to display the data by week in columns. I have done for a week but cannot do to a all weeks in a month.

In my table I want to group the data by id per week and sum it

My sample data is here: [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb580e/5)

**Sample o/p**

```
121212    1212  7646  45647
```

Comment: May be I am missing something but how you are expecting the output from the table which you have provided?

Comment: 4 weeks output in 4 different columns @RahulTripathi

Comment: Will it always be the same 4 weeks or will be a dynamic period, ie the last 4 full weeks?

Comment: I mean 4 weeks for a month

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
SELECT month
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN day between 1 and 7 then Value END) as WEEK_1_VAL
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN day between 8 and 14 then Value END) as WEEK_2_VAL
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN day between 15 and 21 then Value END) as WEEK_3_VAL
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN day between 22 and 28 then Value END) as WEEK_4_VAL
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN day between 29 and 31 then Value END) as WEEK_5_VAL
FROM sample GROUP BY month
;
```

Output

```
month   WEEK_1_VAL  WEEK_2_VAL  WEEK_3_VAL  WEEK_4_VAL  WEEK_5_VAL
12      8           13          1           119.78      11.89
```

Comment: Changed for 7 days a week . @DheerajPatnaik Does this answer .

Answer (score 0):

Do a query where you group by `DATEPART(week, ...)`, which would produce one row per week, and then PIVOT that query to make the rows into columns.